# query to display video links from a table which match inserted checkbox values in another table

Tags: php, mysql, video, checkbox

I need help with a query which I do not have the knowledge to implement. I am aware that mysql functions are deprecated but my website is only a prototype so it is not important for the purpose of this project.

I have a site which is used to display video tutorials for users for training purposes. Users are presented with list of 14 questions with checkboxes, they can tick the relevant checkboxes and view each associated tutorial on the next page.

The user_id of the person logged on also inserts into my database so I can identify who has selected the checkboxes, along with each checkbox value (1 or 0) into a seperate column in my answers table (enisatanswer). Here is my code for inserting which is working fine. The SELECT statement at the start is to maintain my SESSION details of the user, and is used across each page.

```
<?php  
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
header("Location: eNISATVids.php");

@$userID=$_SESSION['user'];
@$checkbox1=$_POST['Log'];
@$checkbox2=$_POST['Worktray'];
@$checkbox3=$_POST['Visual'];
@$checkbox4=$_POST['ChangePd']; 
@$checkbox5=$_POST['Logout'];
@$checkbox6=$_POST['ClientSearch'];
@$checkbox7=$_POST['StartAssessment'];
@$checkbox8=$_POST['Finalise'];
@$checkbox9=$_POST['Print'];
@$checkbox10=$_POST['Hcn'];
@$checkbox11=$_POST['Lcid'];
@$checkbox12=$_POST['Soscare'];
@$checkbox13=$_POST['Reassign'];
@$checkbox14=$_POST['Close'];

    $query="INSERT INTO enisatanswer (user_id,Log,Worktray,Visual,ChangePd,Logout,ClientSearch,StartAssessment,Finalise,Print,Hcn,Lcid,Soscare,Reassign,Close) VALUES 
    ('$userID', '$checkbox1', '$checkbox2','$checkbox3', '$checkbox4', '$checkbox5', '$checkbox6','$checkbox7', '$checkbox8','$checkbox9', '$checkbox10','$checkbox11', '$checkbox12', '$checkbox13', '$checkbox14')";  
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
if($query==true)
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Your choices have inserted Successfully \n \n Please click on Display eNISAT Tutorials at the buttom of the page to view your videos ")</script>';  
   }  
else  
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
   }  
}  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
/<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>
<center>
<h2>Please select the tasks you require assistance with, before clicking DISPLAY ENISAT TUTORIALS:<h2>
<br>
<table align="center" height="0" width="70%" border="1" bgcolor = "white">
   <form  action="" method="post"

   <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">Tick each relevant box:</td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to login</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Log" value="1"></td>   
   <tr>  
      <td>How to manage your worktray</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Worktray" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your visual settings (Colours and text size)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Visual" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your own password on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ChangePd" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to logout of the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Logout" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to search for a client on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ClientSearch" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr> 
      <td>How to start an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="StartAssessment" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>
      <td>How to finalise an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Finalise" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to print an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Print" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to create a client and referral manually through Find on H+C</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Hcn" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from LCID (LCID Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Lcid" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from Soscare (Soscare Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Soscare" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to reassign a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Reassign" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to close a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Close" value="1"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>  
      <td  <td><button name="submit" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='eNISATVids.php'">Display eNISAT Tutorials</button></td>
</tr> 
</table>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

My next page at present displays links in a table for all 14 of my videos from my questions table 'enisatquestion'.

My question is, can anyone help me with a query to only display the video links for the the checkboxes that were selected by the user, instead of them all. I am guessing that in order to do this a variable would need to be created for each column from my 'enisatanswer' table. My columns are (Log,Worktray,Visual etc)

So my query i presume would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM enisatquestion WHERE enisatanswer (Log,Worktray,Visual....) VALUES =1 and user_id = $userID=$_SESSION['user'];
```

I am really not sure about this Statement

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code to display my videos

```
<?php  

    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) header("Location: index.php");

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array( $res );

    $query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion";

    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    /* A default message if the query fails or there are no records */
    $enisatquestion='<h2>Sorry, there are no records</h2>';


    /* you cannot output content outside the html tags, not valid ~ it will work but NO */
    if( $result ) {/* if there is a recordset, proceed and generate html table */
        $enisatquestion = "<table >";
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";
        }
        $enisatquestion .= "</table>";    
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="home.php?home">Return to Homepage</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>
    <center>
   <h2>Click on the each link to open your tutorial in Windows Media Player<h2>
   <br>
    <?php
        /* output the html table here, below your header */
        echo $enisatquestion;
        /*
            If the query failed then the default gets displayed
        */
    ?>  
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jay, but I stated in my op that I know I am using them but it is not important (I am using 5.5). I do not have time to learn a new way as I am creating this for a uni project with very little time to do so. Any suggestions for my question? i will save your link for future reference though thank you

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: My system is a throw away prototype, It will not be used in the public domain and everything is done on localhost. I have 2 weeks left to get this working from 8 weeks in total to learn how to code, which I have no experience of before. On top of working full-time whilst doing my studies and a crazy 1 year old at home to look after. Cut me some slack and thanks for attempting to answer my question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Why are you suppressing all of your variables with `@`? I know how crazy it canbe and honestly I am cutting you some slack, it is your teachers who I have a beef with.

Comment: You do not need `VALUES` in a `SELECT`. That is meant for `INSERT` queries. `SELECT * FROM enisatquestion WHERE enisatanswer =1 and user_id = $userID=$_SESSION['user'];`

Comment: Because I was getting undefined index for the checkboxes which were not ticked.

Comment: Checkboxes that are not checked are not sent via POST. You should handle verification for those differently, rather than suppression.

Comment: That query doesnt work Jay, enisatanswer is my table name, i thought I would have to select from the column

Comment: Since you're selecting `*` you're not naming columns. You should use `SELECT * FROM enisatanswer ....` then.

Comment: So SELECT * From enisatquestion AND SELECT * From enisatanswer WHERE (how do I get the value of 1 from each separate column in my table  here) AND userid = etc. Would that be right?

Comment: Are you selecting so that each column's value is equal to 1? If so it would be `WHERE columna = 1 AND columnb = 1 AND so on and so forth...`

Comment: Can you help me with my question please? @RamRaider